# Ruby On Rails: form routing - search as subfolder instead of param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes

So I have this form:

```
<%= form_tag("/product", method: "get") do %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:barcode_number) %>
    <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

It searches as **/product?barcode_number="barcode_number"**

But I want it to search like **/product/"barcode_number"**

It both works (when typing in address bar)

In my routes I have product/:barcode_number defined.

How do I do this?

Comment: This is not possible with pure HTML. You will need to use JavaScript here, or redirect from the server-side. Forms will always use parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with javascript by changing the target of the form when it's submitted.

Example with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').on('submit'), function() {
    $(this).target = '/product/' + $('input[name=barcode_number]').value;
  }
});
```